# Distributional convergence of integrals

Tags: distribution-theory, cauchy-principal-value

Hi :) I'm studying distributions and I would like to know if I'm doing this right.
Let's take an ordinary function $$f(x)=\int_0 ^\infty dk\ \sin(kx)$$ and we want to study the functional on a test function 
$$
\left<T_f,\phi\right>
 = \int dx\ f(k)\phi(x)
 = \int _{-\infty} ^\infty dx \int _0 ^\infty dk\ \sin(kx)\phi(x)
$$
To study the functional we add the cut off $e^{-\alpha k}$, then evaluate the limit $\alpha\rightarrow 0$. So
$$
\left<T_f,\phi\right>
   = \int _{-\infty} ^\infty dx \int _0 ^\infty dk \sin(kx)\phi(x)e^{-\alpha k}
$$
Since the double integral converges uniformly in $k$ and $x$ we can swtich the integration order and study
$$f_\alpha(x)=\int_0 ^\infty dk \sin(kx) e^{-\alpha k}=\frac{x}{x^2 + \alpha^2}$$
Substituting we get
$$
\left<T_{f_\alpha},\phi\right>
 = \int _{-\infty} ^\infty dx \frac{x}{x^2 + \alpha ^2}\phi(x)
 = \left<P.V. \frac{x}{x^2+\alpha^2},\phi\right> \xrightarrow{\alpha \to 0}\left<P.V. \frac{1}{x}, \phi\right>$$
So, in a distributional sense, I have $$f(x)=\int_0 ^\infty dk \sin(kx)=P.V. \frac{1}{x}$$ where $P.V.$ denotes the principal value.
Is this correct?

Comment: You don't need $P.V.$ in front of $\frac{x}{x^2+\alpha^2}$.

Comment: How do you know that $\frac{x}{x^2+\alpha^2} \to P.V. \frac{1}{x}$? Is that something you have proved before in the course?

Comment: That's what's bugs me. I took this from the appendix of a book. I think it evaluate the limit "inside the $P. V. $"

Comment: By the way, if the definition of $f$ is taken literally then $f(x)$ is only defined for $x=0$ so already that formula should be interpreted in a distributional way.